# General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16)

Tags: php, sql-server

Im facing issue while trying to connect to my SQL server machine with the below code.

```
$hostname = '10.11.22.33';                 
$username = 'siddharth';
$password = '1234';
$dbname = 'airport';
$port='1433';

$dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF-8", $username, $password);
$arraykey=array_keys($data); 
$array=$data[$arraykey[0]]; 

try 
{
 //$count = $dbh->exec('INSERT INTO dbo.gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime) VALUES ("' . implode('", "', $array) . '")' ) or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true)); 
 // Changed from double quotes to single while inserting VALUES
 $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO dbo.gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $array) . "')" ) or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true)); 
 $dbh = null;
echo 'Data Successfully inserted!!<br />';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I get the below error when i execute this script.

> Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 207 [2] => General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [] [3] => -1 [4] => 16 )

If i print_r $dbh i get just PDO()

Whats wrong in PDO insert.

Sounds strange and playing with me for a while.

But the same pdo object i use in the below script for select query, i get the 'It is working' message!!

```
$hostname = '10.11.22.33';                 
$username = 'siddharth';
$password = '1234';
$dbname = 'airport';
$port='1433';
try {
$dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=$hostname:1433;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF-8", $username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT 'It is working' AS name";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['name'] . "\n";
}
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
print $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: in your insertion query you are using gmr database while you are connecting to `airport` database with PDO

Comment: Airport is the DB and gmr is the table....i changed the quotes and its inserting now..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tried to insert with hard coded values with single qoutes and it got inserted.

So changed the quotes in the insert statement from

```
 'INSERT INTO gmr VALUES (" ' . implode(' ", " ', $array) . ' ")' )
```

to

```
"INSERT INTO gmr VALUES (' " . implode(" ', ' ", $array) . " ')" )
```